# List of all Unicode's open/close brackets

Tags: unicode, parentheses, curly-braces, square-bracket, braces

What is a list of every Unicode bracket-like characters (including, for example: `{}[]()<>`)? What is a good way to search for Unicode characters?

Comment: This post is the second result for "unicode brackets". The first is [an actual list](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_matching_brackets.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_matching_brackets.html)).

Answer (score 185, accepted):

There is a [plain-text database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/) of information about every Unicode character available from the Unicode Consortium; the format is described in [Unicode Annex #44](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/). The primary information is contained in [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt). Open and close punctuation characters are denoted with `Ps` (punctuation start) and `Pe` (punctuation end) in the General_Category field (the third field, delimited by `;`). Look for those character, and you'll find what you're looking for.

Note that not all characters that you consider brackets may be listed; for instance, quotation marks (including "«»"). are indicated with `Pi` and `Pf` (initial and final punctuation), so you might want to include those as well. And some character, like `<` and `>`, are used as brackets in some contexts (such as HTML/XML), while they are considered math symbols (`Sm`) in UnicodeData.txt. Those you are going to have to find by hand; there is no pre-determined listing of those.

Here's a quick Bash script to get this information, and its output. I've included both brackets and quotes. (note: on some Bash implementations UTF-8 printing has a bug that causes it to print U+00AB "«" and U+00BB "»" as "?", and some terminals don't have the ability to render all characters correctly.)

```
while IFS=';' read number name category rest
do 
    if [[ "$category" =~ Ps|Pe|Pi|Pf ]]
    then 
        printf "%s (U+%s, %s): \u"$number"\n" "$name" "$number" "$category"
    fi
done <UnicodeData.txt
```

```
LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+0028, Ps): (
RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+0029, Pe): )
LEFT SQUARE BRACKET (U+005B, Ps): [
RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET (U+005D, Pe): ]
LEFT CURLY BRACKET (U+007B, Ps): {
RIGHT CURLY BRACKET (U+007D, Pe): }
LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+00AB, Pi): «
RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+00BB, Pf): »
TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYON (U+0F3A, Ps): ༺
TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYAS (U+0F3B, Pe): ༻
TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYON (U+0F3C, Ps): ༼
TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYAS (U+0F3D, Pe): ༽
OGHAM FEATHER MARK (U+169B, Ps): ᚛
OGHAM REVERSED FEATHER MARK (U+169C, Pe): ᚜
LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018, Pi): ‘
RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019, Pf): ’
SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201A, Ps): ‚
SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201B, Pi): ‛
LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201C, Pi): “
RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201D, Pf): ”
DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201E, Ps): „
DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201F, Pi): ‟
SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2039, Pi): ‹
SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+203A, Pf): ›
LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL (U+2045, Ps): ⁅
RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL (U+2046, Pe): ⁆
SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+207D, Ps): ⁽
SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+207E, Pe): ⁾
SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+208D, Ps): ₍
SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+208E, Pe): ₎
LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET (U+2329, Ps): 〈
RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET (U+232A, Pe): 〉
MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT (U+2768, Ps): ❨
MEDIUM RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT (U+2769, Pe): ❩
MEDIUM FLATTENED LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT (U+276A, Ps): ❪
MEDIUM FLATTENED RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT (U+276B, Pe): ❫
MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+276C, Ps): ❬
MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+276D, Pe): ❭
HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT (U+276E, Ps): ❮
HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT (U+276F, Pe): ❯
HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2770, Ps): ❰
HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2771, Pe): ❱
LIGHT LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2772, Ps): ❲
LIGHT RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2773, Pe): ❳
MEDIUM LEFT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2774, Ps): ❴
MEDIUM RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+2775, Pe): ❵
LEFT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER (U+27C5, Ps): ⟅
RIGHT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER (U+27C6, Pe): ⟆
MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET (U+27E6, Ps): ⟦
MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET (U+27E7, Pe): ⟧
MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET (U+27E8, Ps): ⟨
MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET (U+27E9, Pe): ⟩
MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+27EA, Ps): ⟪
MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+27EB, Pe): ⟫
MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+27EC, Ps): ⟬
MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+27ED, Pe): ⟭
MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS (U+27EE, Ps): ⟮
MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS (U+27EF, Pe): ⟯
LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET (U+2983, Ps): ⦃
RIGHT WHITE CURLY BRACKET (U+2984, Pe): ⦄
LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS (U+2985, Ps): ⦅
RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS (U+2986, Pe): ⦆
Z NOTATION LEFT IMAGE BRACKET (U+2987, Ps): ⦇
Z NOTATION RIGHT IMAGE BRACKET (U+2988, Pe): ⦈
Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET (U+2989, Ps): ⦉
Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET (U+298A, Pe): ⦊
LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR (U+298B, Ps): ⦋
RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR (U+298C, Pe): ⦌
LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER (U+298D, Ps): ⦍
RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER (U+298E, Pe): ⦎
LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER (U+298F, Ps): ⦏
RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER (U+2990, Pe): ⦐
LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT (U+2991, Ps): ⦑
RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT (U+2992, Pe): ⦒
LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET (U+2993, Ps): ⦓
RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET (U+2994, Pe): ⦔
DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET (U+2995, Ps): ⦕
DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET (U+2996, Pe): ⦖
LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+2997, Ps): ⦗
RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+2998, Pe): ⦘
LEFT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D8, Ps): ⧘
RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D9, Pe): ⧙
LEFT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE (U+29DA, Ps): ⧚
RIGHT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE (U+29DB, Pe): ⧛
LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET (U+29FC, Ps): ⧼
RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET (U+29FD, Pe): ⧽
LEFT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET (U+2E02, Pi): ⸂
RIGHT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET (U+2E03, Pf): ⸃
LEFT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET (U+2E04, Pi): ⸄
RIGHT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET (U+2E05, Pf): ⸅
LEFT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET (U+2E09, Pi): ⸉
RIGHT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET (U+2E0A, Pf): ⸊
LEFT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET (U+2E0C, Pi): ⸌
RIGHT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET (U+2E0D, Pf): ⸍
LEFT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET (U+2E1C, Pi): ⸜
RIGHT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET (U+2E1D, Pf): ⸝
LEFT VERTICAL BAR WITH QUILL (U+2E20, Pi): ⸠
RIGHT VERTICAL BAR WITH QUILL (U+2E21, Pf): ⸡
TOP LEFT HALF BRACKET (U+2E22, Ps): ⸢
TOP RIGHT HALF BRACKET (U+2E23, Pe): ⸣
BOTTOM LEFT HALF BRACKET (U+2E24, Ps): ⸤
BOTTOM RIGHT HALF BRACKET (U+2E25, Pe): ⸥
LEFT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET (U+2E26, Ps): ⸦
RIGHT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET (U+2E27, Pe): ⸧
LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS (U+2E28, Ps): ⸨
RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS (U+2E29, Pe): ⸩
LEFT ANGLE BRACKET (U+3008, Ps): 〈
RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET (U+3009, Pe): 〉
LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+300A, Ps): 《
RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+300B, Pe): 》
LEFT CORNER BRACKET (U+300C, Ps): 「
RIGHT CORNER BRACKET (U+300D, Pe): 」
LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET (U+300E, Ps): 『
RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET (U+300F, Pe): 』
LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3010, Ps): 【
RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3011, Pe): 】
LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3014, Ps): 〔
RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3015, Pe): 〕
LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3016, Ps): 〖
RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3017, Pe): 〗
LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3018, Ps): 〘
RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3019, Pe): 〙
LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET (U+301A, Ps): 〚
RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET (U+301B, Pe): 〛
REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK (U+301D, Ps): 〝
DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK (U+301E, Pe): 〞
LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK (U+301F, Pe): 〟
ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+FD3E, Ps): ﴾
ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+FD3F, Pe): ﴿
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+FE17, Ps): ︗
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRAKCET (U+FE18, Pe): ︘
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+FE35, Ps): ︵
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+FE36, Pe): ︶
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CURLY BRACKET (U+FE37, Ps): ︷
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET (U+FE38, Pe): ︸
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+FE39, Ps): ︹
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+FE3A, Pe): ︺
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+FE3B, Ps): ︻
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+FE3C, Pe): ︼
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3D, Ps): ︽
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3E, Pe): ︾
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3F, Ps): ︿
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE40, Pe): ﹀
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CORNER BRACKET (U+FE41, Ps): ﹁
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CORNER BRACKET (U+FE42, Pe): ﹂
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET (U+FE43, Ps): ﹃
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET (U+FE44, Pe): ﹄
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT SQUARE BRACKET (U+FE47, Ps): ﹇
PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET (U+FE48, Pe): ﹈
SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+FE59, Ps): ﹙
SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+FE5A, Pe): ﹚
SMALL LEFT CURLY BRACKET (U+FE5B, Ps): ﹛
SMALL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET (U+FE5C, Pe): ﹜
SMALL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+FE5D, Ps): ﹝
SMALL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+FE5E, Pe): ﹞
FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+FF08, Ps): （
FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+FF09, Pe): ）
FULLWIDTH LEFT SQUARE BRACKET (U+FF3B, Ps): ［
FULLWIDTH RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET (U+FF3D, Pe): ］
FULLWIDTH LEFT CURLY BRACKET (U+FF5B, Ps): ｛
FULLWIDTH RIGHT CURLY BRACKET (U+FF5D, Pe): ｝
FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS (U+FF5F, Ps): ｟
FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS (U+FF60, Pe): ｠
HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET (U+FF62, Ps): ｢
HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET (U+FF63, Pe): ｣
```

Comment: For ease of use, I put this list up as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/8f9d51a1dc365f2e64fa).

Comment: @ClayBridges Thanks! While you're at it, you should be sure to fix the problem that I pointed out where Bash had trouble with U+00AB "«" and U+00BB "»". I didn't bother to manually edit the list because I was just using this as an example of parsing the list, but if you're going to present a separate list you should probably fix it.

Comment: You probably also want to include things like ⋘ (VERY MUCH LESS-THAN), which is categorised as Sm (Symbol, Math). And ⚟ THREE LINES CONVERGING LEFT.

Comment: As I said in my answer: "some characters, like `<` and `>`, are used as brackets in some contexts, while they are considered math symbols in `UnicodeData.txt`. Those you are going to have to find by hand; there is no pre-determined listing of those." The characters that you mention fall into that category; they are not intended for use as brackets, but could possibly be used as such. VERY MUCH LESS-THAN is a comparison operator, not a bracket, similar to LESS THAN (`<`), which is also an operator but due to the limited ASCII character set has also been reused as an angle bracket.

Comment: The plain-text database now has two files listing all mirrored characters: BidiBrackets.txt and a BidiMirroring.txt. One of them lists brackets only, while one also lists other characters like **≤** and **≥**.

Comment: Let me indeed mention that some people use $<x,y>$ to denote scalar product, but this is wrong and ugly,  the spacing will be wrong since <> are operators and are spaced as such; the correct (La)TeX is $\langle x,y\rangle $.

Comment: What about ＞ (U+FF1E), Full width greater than sign, different from >?

Comment: MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT - for all those times Linux just refuses to add a normal bracket in!

Answer (score 33):

There's no canonical list of this in Unicode—you'll have to define your own list. You could start by using Python's [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) module to explore the Unicode database. Note that this won't find things like `<>` that are used as braces even though they have other official meanings, namely as less-than and greater-than signs.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re
import unicodedata

for i in range(0x10000):
    char = unichr(i)
    category = unicodedata.category(char)
    name = unicodedata.name(char, '')
    if ('bracket' in name.lower() or 'paren' in name.lower()
            or category in ['Ps', 'Pe']):
        print 'U+%04x %s %s %c' % (i, category, name, char)
```

Output:

```
U+0028 Ps LEFT PARENTHESIS (
U+0029 Pe RIGHT PARENTHESIS )
U+005b Ps LEFT SQUARE BRACKET [
U+005d Pe RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET ]
U+007b Ps LEFT CURLY BRACKET {
U+007d Pe RIGHT CURLY BRACKET }
U+0f3a Ps TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYON ༺
U+0f3b Pe TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYAS ༻
U+0f3c Ps TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYON ༼
U+0f3d Pe TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYAS ༽
U+169b Ps OGHAM FEATHER MARK ᚛
U+169c Pe OGHAM REVERSED FEATHER MARK ᚜
U+201a Ps SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK ‚
U+201e Ps DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK „
U+2045 Ps LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL ⁅
U+2046 Pe RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL ⁆
U+207d Ps SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS ⁽
U+207e Pe SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS ⁾
U+208d Ps SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS ₍
U+208e Pe SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS ₎
U+2329 Ps LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET 〈
U+232a Pe RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET 〉
U+239b Sm LEFT PARENTHESIS UPPER HOOK ⎛
U+239c Sm LEFT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION ⎜
U+239d Sm LEFT PARENTHESIS LOWER HOOK ⎝
U+239e Sm RIGHT PARENTHESIS UPPER HOOK ⎞
U+239f Sm RIGHT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION ⎟
U+23a0 Sm RIGHT PARENTHESIS LOWER HOOK ⎠
U+23a1 Sm LEFT SQUARE BRACKET UPPER CORNER ⎡
U+23a2 Sm LEFT SQUARE BRACKET EXTENSION ⎢
U+23a3 Sm LEFT SQUARE BRACKET LOWER CORNER ⎣
U+23a4 Sm RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET UPPER CORNER ⎤
U+23a5 Sm RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET EXTENSION ⎥
U+23a6 Sm RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET LOWER CORNER ⎦
U+23a7 Sm LEFT CURLY BRACKET UPPER HOOK ⎧
U+23a8 Sm LEFT CURLY BRACKET MIDDLE PIECE ⎨
U+23a9 Sm LEFT CURLY BRACKET LOWER HOOK ⎩
U+23aa Sm CURLY BRACKET EXTENSION ⎪
U+23ab Sm RIGHT CURLY BRACKET UPPER HOOK ⎫
U+23ac Sm RIGHT CURLY BRACKET MIDDLE PIECE ⎬
U+23ad Sm RIGHT CURLY BRACKET LOWER HOOK ⎭
U+23b0 Sm UPPER LEFT OR LOWER RIGHT CURLY BRACKET SECTION ⎰
U+23b1 Sm UPPER RIGHT OR LOWER LEFT CURLY BRACKET SECTION ⎱
U+23b4 So TOP SQUARE BRACKET ⎴
U+23b5 So BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET ⎵
U+23b6 So BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET OVER TOP SQUARE BRACKET ⎶
U+23dc Sm TOP PARENTHESIS ⏜
U+23dd Sm BOTTOM PARENTHESIS ⏝
U+23de Sm TOP CURLY BRACKET ⏞
U+23df Sm BOTTOM CURLY BRACKET ⏟
U+23e0 Sm TOP TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⏠
U+23e1 Sm BOTTOM TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⏡
U+2474 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT ONE ⑴
U+2475 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT TWO ⑵
U+2476 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT THREE ⑶
U+2477 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT FOUR ⑷
U+2478 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT FIVE ⑸
U+2479 No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT SIX ⑹
U+247a No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT SEVEN ⑺
U+247b No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT EIGHT ⑻
U+247c No PARENTHESIZED DIGIT NINE ⑼
U+247d No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER TEN ⑽
U+247e No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER ELEVEN ⑾
U+247f No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER TWELVE ⑿
U+2480 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER THIRTEEN ⒀
U+2481 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER FOURTEEN ⒁
U+2482 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER FIFTEEN ⒂
U+2483 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER SIXTEEN ⒃
U+2484 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER SEVENTEEN ⒄
U+2485 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER EIGHTEEN ⒅
U+2486 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER NINETEEN ⒆
U+2487 No PARENTHESIZED NUMBER TWENTY ⒇
U+249c So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER A ⒜
U+249d So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER B ⒝
U+249e So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER C ⒞
U+249f So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER D ⒟
U+24a0 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER E ⒠
U+24a1 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER F ⒡
U+24a2 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER G ⒢
U+24a3 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER H ⒣
U+24a4 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER I ⒤
U+24a5 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER J ⒥
U+24a6 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER K ⒦
U+24a7 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER L ⒧
U+24a8 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER M ⒨
U+24a9 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER N ⒩
U+24aa So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER O ⒪
U+24ab So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER P ⒫
U+24ac So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER Q ⒬
U+24ad So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER R ⒭
U+24ae So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER S ⒮
U+24af So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER T ⒯
U+24b0 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER U ⒰
U+24b1 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER V ⒱
U+24b2 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER W ⒲
U+24b3 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER X ⒳
U+24b4 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER Y ⒴
U+24b5 So PARENTHESIZED LATIN SMALL LETTER Z ⒵
U+2768 Ps MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT ❨
U+2769 Pe MEDIUM RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT ❩
U+276a Ps MEDIUM FLATTENED LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT ❪
U+276b Pe MEDIUM FLATTENED RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT ❫
U+276c Ps MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT ❬
U+276d Pe MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT ❭
U+276e Ps HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT ❮
U+276f Pe HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT ❯
U+2770 Ps HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT ❰
U+2771 Pe HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT ❱
U+2772 Ps LIGHT LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT ❲
U+2773 Pe LIGHT RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT ❳
U+2774 Ps MEDIUM LEFT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT ❴
U+2775 Pe MEDIUM RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT ❵
U+27c5 Ps LEFT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER ⟅
U+27c6 Pe RIGHT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER ⟆
U+27e6 Ps MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET ⟦
U+27e7 Pe MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET ⟧
U+27e8 Ps MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET ⟨
U+27e9 Pe MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET ⟩
U+27ea Ps MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET ⟪
U+27eb Pe MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET ⟫
U+27ec Ps MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⟬
U+27ed Pe MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⟭
U+27ee Ps MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS ⟮
U+27ef Pe MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS ⟯
U+2983 Ps LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET ⦃
U+2984 Pe RIGHT WHITE CURLY BRACKET ⦄
U+2985 Ps LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS ⦅
U+2986 Pe RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS ⦆
U+2987 Ps Z NOTATION LEFT IMAGE BRACKET ⦇
U+2988 Pe Z NOTATION RIGHT IMAGE BRACKET ⦈
U+2989 Ps Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET ⦉
U+298a Pe Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET ⦊
U+298b Ps LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR ⦋
U+298c Pe RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR ⦌
U+298d Ps LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER ⦍
U+298e Pe RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER ⦎
U+298f Ps LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER ⦏
U+2990 Pe RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER ⦐
U+2991 Ps LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT ⦑
U+2992 Pe RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT ⦒
U+2993 Ps LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET ⦓
U+2994 Pe RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET ⦔
U+2995 Ps DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET ⦕
U+2996 Pe DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET ⦖
U+2997 Ps LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⦗
U+2998 Pe RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⦘
U+29d8 Ps LEFT WIGGLY FENCE ⧘
U+29d9 Pe RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE ⧙
U+29da Ps LEFT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE ⧚
U+29db Pe RIGHT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE ⧛
U+29fc Ps LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET ⧼
U+29fd Pe RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET ⧽
U+2e02 Pi LEFT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET ⸂
U+2e03 Pf RIGHT SUBSTITUTION BRACKET ⸃
U+2e04 Pi LEFT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET ⸄
U+2e05 Pf RIGHT DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET ⸅
U+2e09 Pi LEFT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET ⸉
U+2e0a Pf RIGHT TRANSPOSITION BRACKET ⸊
U+2e0c Pi LEFT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET ⸌
U+2e0d Pf RIGHT RAISED OMISSION BRACKET ⸍
U+2e1c Pi LEFT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET ⸜
U+2e1d Pf RIGHT LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET ⸝
U+2e22 Ps TOP LEFT HALF BRACKET ⸢
U+2e23 Pe TOP RIGHT HALF BRACKET ⸣
U+2e24 Ps BOTTOM LEFT HALF BRACKET ⸤
U+2e25 Pe BOTTOM RIGHT HALF BRACKET ⸥
U+2e26 Ps LEFT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET ⸦
U+2e27 Pe RIGHT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET ⸧
U+2e28 Ps LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS ⸨
U+2e29 Pe RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS ⸩
U+3008 Ps LEFT ANGLE BRACKET 〈
U+3009 Pe RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET 〉
U+300a Ps LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET 《
U+300b Pe RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET 》
U+300c Ps LEFT CORNER BRACKET 「
U+300d Pe RIGHT CORNER BRACKET 」
U+300e Ps LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET 『
U+300f Pe RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET 』
U+3010 Ps LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET 【
U+3011 Pe RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET 】
U+3014 Ps LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET 〔
U+3015 Pe RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET 〕
U+3016 Ps LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET 〖
U+3017 Pe RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET 〗
U+3018 Ps LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET 〘
U+3019 Pe RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET 〙
U+301a Ps LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET 〚
U+301b Pe RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET 〛
U+301d Ps REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK 〝
U+301e Pe DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK 〞
U+301f Pe LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK 〟
U+3200 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL KIYEOK ㈀
U+3201 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL NIEUN ㈁
U+3202 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL TIKEUT ㈂
U+3203 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL RIEUL ㈃
U+3204 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL MIEUM ㈄
U+3205 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL PIEUP ㈅
U+3206 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL SIOS ㈆
U+3207 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL IEUNG ㈇
U+3208 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL CIEUC ㈈
U+3209 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL CHIEUCH ㈉
U+320a So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL KHIEUKH ㈊
U+320b So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL THIEUTH ㈋
U+320c So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL PHIEUPH ㈌
U+320d So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL HIEUH ㈍
U+320e So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL KIYEOK A ㈎
U+320f So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL NIEUN A ㈏
U+3210 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL TIKEUT A ㈐
U+3211 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL RIEUL A ㈑
U+3212 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL MIEUM A ㈒
U+3213 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL PIEUP A ㈓
U+3214 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL SIOS A ㈔
U+3215 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL IEUNG A ㈕
U+3216 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL CIEUC A ㈖
U+3217 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL CHIEUCH A ㈗
U+3218 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL KHIEUKH A ㈘
U+3219 So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL THIEUTH A ㈙
U+321a So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL PHIEUPH A ㈚
U+321b So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL HIEUH A ㈛
U+321c So PARENTHESIZED HANGUL CIEUC U ㈜
U+321d So PARENTHESIZED KOREAN CHARACTER OJEON ㈝
U+321e So PARENTHESIZED KOREAN CHARACTER O HU ㈞
U+3220 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH ONE ㈠
U+3221 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH TWO ㈡
U+3222 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH THREE ㈢
U+3223 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH FOUR ㈣
U+3224 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH FIVE ㈤
U+3225 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SIX ㈥
U+3226 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SEVEN ㈦
U+3227 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH EIGHT ㈧
U+3228 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH NINE ㈨
U+3229 No PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH TEN ㈩
U+322a So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH MOON ㈪
U+322b So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH FIRE ㈫
U+322c So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH WATER ㈬
U+322d So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH WOOD ㈭
U+322e So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH METAL ㈮
U+322f So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH EARTH ㈯
U+3230 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SUN ㈰
U+3231 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH STOCK ㈱
U+3232 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH HAVE ㈲
U+3233 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SOCIETY ㈳
U+3234 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH NAME ㈴
U+3235 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SPECIAL ㈵
U+3236 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH FINANCIAL ㈶
U+3237 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH CONGRATULATION ㈷
U+3238 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH LABOR ㈸
U+3239 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH REPRESENT ㈹
U+323a So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH CALL ㈺
U+323b So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH STUDY ㈻
U+323c So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SUPERVISE ㈼
U+323d So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH ENTERPRISE ㈽
U+323e So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH RESOURCE ㈾
U+323f So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH ALLIANCE ㈿
U+3240 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH FESTIVAL ㉀
U+3241 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH REST ㉁
U+3242 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH SELF ㉂
U+3243 So PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH REACH ㉃
U+fd3e Ps ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS ﴾
U+fd3f Pe ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS ﴿
U+fe17 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET ︗
U+fe18 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRAKCET ︘
U+fe35 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT PARENTHESIS ︵
U+fe36 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT PARENTHESIS ︶
U+fe37 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CURLY BRACKET ︷
U+fe38 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ︸
U+fe39 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ︹
U+fe3a Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ︺
U+fe3b Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET ︻
U+fe3c Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET ︼
U+fe3d Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET ︽
U+fe3e Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET ︾
U+fe3f Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET ︿
U+fe40 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET ﹀
U+fe41 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CORNER BRACKET ﹁
U+fe42 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CORNER BRACKET ﹂
U+fe43 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET ﹃
U+fe44 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET ﹄
U+fe47 Ps PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT SQUARE BRACKET ﹇
U+fe48 Pe PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET ﹈
U+fe59 Ps SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS ﹙
U+fe5a Pe SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS ﹚
U+fe5b Ps SMALL LEFT CURLY BRACKET ﹛
U+fe5c Pe SMALL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ﹜
U+fe5d Ps SMALL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ﹝
U+fe5e Pe SMALL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ﹞
U+ff08 Ps FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS （
U+ff09 Pe FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS ）
U+ff3b Ps FULLWIDTH LEFT SQUARE BRACKET ［
U+ff3d Pe FULLWIDTH RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET ］
U+ff5b Ps FULLWIDTH LEFT CURLY BRACKET ｛
U+ff5d Pe FULLWIDTH RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ｝
U+ff5f Ps FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS ｟
U+ff60 Pe FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS ｠
U+ff62 Ps HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET ｢
U+ff63 Pe HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET ｣
```

Comment: You might want to include `'brace'` in your list of terms too. I think there are a couple. Maybe `'Ps' | 'Pe'` catches them, though.

Answer (score 27):

Recent Unicode releases have added a property Bidi_Paired_Bracket that gives what Unicode thinks is the answer to this question.  This is different from the ones that are mirrored.  There are 60 bracket-pairs as of Unicode 8.0.

The following table maps each to its mate.  The first column gives a code point; the second gives the Unicode version it was introduced in; the third shows the mapping, and the final column gives the mapping by character name.

Also, for looking at the Unicode character database, Perl5 is packaged with the module *Unicode::UCD*, with many functions for inspecting things, including new ones in Perl v5.22 that will output the value of all properties for a given code point.  Unicode::Tussle on [CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) offers similar and other functionality.

```
0028 1.1 '(' => ')';  LEFT PARENTHESIS => RIGHT PARENTHESIS
0029 1.1 ')' => '(';  RIGHT PARENTHESIS => LEFT PARENTHESIS
005B 1.1 '[' => ']';  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET => RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
005D 1.1 ']' => '[';  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET => LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
007B 1.1 '{' => '}';  LEFT CURLY BRACKET => RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
007D 1.1 '}' => '{';  RIGHT CURLY BRACKET => LEFT CURLY BRACKET
0F3A 2.0 '༺' => '༻';  TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYON => TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYAS
0F3B 2.0 '༻' => '༺';  TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYAS => TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYON
0F3C 2.0 '༼' => '༽';  TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYON => TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYAS
0F3D 2.0 '༽' => '༼';  TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYAS => TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYON
169B 3.0 '᚛' => '᚜';  OGHAM FEATHER MARK => OGHAM REVERSED FEATHER MARK
169C 3.0 '᚜' => '᚛';  OGHAM REVERSED FEATHER MARK => OGHAM FEATHER MARK
2045 1.1 '⁅' => '⁆';  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL => RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL
2046 1.1 '⁆' => '⁅';  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL => LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL
207D 1.1 '⁽' => '⁾';  SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS => SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
207E 1.1 '⁾' => '⁽';  SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS => SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
208D 1.1 '₍' => '₎';  SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS => SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
208E 1.1 '₎' => '₍';  SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS => SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
2308 1.1 '⌈' => '⌉';  LEFT CEILING => RIGHT CEILING
2309 1.1 '⌉' => '⌈';  RIGHT CEILING => LEFT CEILING
230A 1.1 '⌊' => '⌋';  LEFT FLOOR => RIGHT FLOOR
230B 1.1 '⌋' => '⌊';  RIGHT FLOOR => LEFT FLOOR
2329 1.1 '⟨' => '⟩';  LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET => RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
232A 1.1 '⟩' => '⟨';  RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET => LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
2768 3.2 '❨' => '❩';  MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT => MEDIUM RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
2769 3.2 '❩' => '❨';  MEDIUM RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT => MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
276A 3.2 '❪' => '❫';  MEDIUM FLATTENED LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT => MEDIUM FLATTENED RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
276B 3.2 '❫' => '❪';  MEDIUM FLATTENED RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT => MEDIUM FLATTENED LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
276C 3.2 '❬' => '❭';  MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT => MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
276D 3.2 '❭' => '❬';  MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT => MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
276E 3.2 '❮' => '❯';  HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT => HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
276F 3.2 '❯' => '❮';  HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT => HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
2770 3.2 '❰' => '❱';  HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT => HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
2771 3.2 '❱' => '❰';  HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT => HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
2772 3.2 '❲' => '❳';  LIGHT LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT => LIGHT RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT
2773 3.2 '❳' => '❲';  LIGHT RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT => LIGHT LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT
2774 3.2 '❴' => '❵';  MEDIUM LEFT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT => MEDIUM RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT
2775 3.2 '❵' => '❴';  MEDIUM RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT => MEDIUM LEFT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT
27C5 4.1 '⟅' => '⟆';  LEFT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER => RIGHT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER
27C6 4.1 '⟆' => '⟅';  RIGHT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER => LEFT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER
27E6 3.2 '⟦' => '⟧';  MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
27E7 3.2 '⟧' => '⟦';  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
27E8 3.2 '⟨' => '⟩';  MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
27E9 3.2 '⟩' => '⟨';  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
27EA 3.2 '⟪' => '⟫';  MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
27EB 3.2 '⟫' => '⟪';  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
27EC 5.1 '⟬' => '⟭';  MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
27ED 5.1 '⟭' => '⟬';  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
27EE 5.1 '⟮' => '⟯';  MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS => MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
27EF 5.1 '⟯' => '⟮';  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS => MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
2983 3.2 '⦃' => '⦄';  LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET => RIGHT WHITE CURLY BRACKET
2984 3.2 '⦄' => '⦃';  RIGHT WHITE CURLY BRACKET => LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET
2985 3.2 '⦅' => '⦆';  LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS => RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
2986 3.2 '⦆' => '⦅';  RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS => LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
2987 3.2 '⦇' => '⦈';  Z NOTATION LEFT IMAGE BRACKET => Z NOTATION RIGHT IMAGE BRACKET
2988 3.2 '⦈' => '⦇';  Z NOTATION RIGHT IMAGE BRACKET => Z NOTATION LEFT IMAGE BRACKET
2989 3.2 '⦉' => '⦊';  Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET => Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET
298A 3.2 '⦊' => '⦉';  Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET => Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET
298B 3.2 '⦋' => '⦌';  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR => RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR
298C 3.2 '⦌' => '⦋';  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR => LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR
298D 3.2 '⦍' => '⦐';  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER => RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER
298E 3.2 '⦎' => '⦏';  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER => LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER
298F 3.2 '⦏' => '⦎';  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER => RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER
2990 3.2 '⦐' => '⦍';  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER => LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER
2991 3.2 '⦑' => '⦒';  LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT => RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
2992 3.2 '⦒' => '⦑';  RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT => LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
2993 3.2 '⦓' => '⦔';  LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET => RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
2994 3.2 '⦔' => '⦓';  RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET => LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
2995 3.2 '⦕' => '⦖';  DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET => DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
2996 3.2 '⦖' => '⦕';  DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET => DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
2997 3.2 '⦗' => '⦘';  LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
2998 3.2 '⦘' => '⦗';  RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
29D8 3.2 '⧘' => '⧙';  LEFT WIGGLY FENCE => RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE
29D9 3.2 '⧙' => '⧘';  RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE => LEFT WIGGLY FENCE
29DA 3.2 '⧚' => '⧛';  LEFT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE => RIGHT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE
29DB 3.2 '⧛' => '⧚';  RIGHT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE => LEFT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE
29FC 3.2 '⧼' => '⧽';  LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET => RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
29FD 3.2 '⧽' => '⧼';  RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET => LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
2E22 5.1 '⸢' => '⸣';  TOP LEFT HALF BRACKET => TOP RIGHT HALF BRACKET
2E23 5.1 '⸣' => '⸢';  TOP RIGHT HALF BRACKET => TOP LEFT HALF BRACKET
2E24 5.1 '⸤' => '⸥';  BOTTOM LEFT HALF BRACKET => BOTTOM RIGHT HALF BRACKET
2E25 5.1 '⸥' => '⸤';  BOTTOM RIGHT HALF BRACKET => BOTTOM LEFT HALF BRACKET
2E26 5.1 '⸦' => '⸧';  LEFT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET => RIGHT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET
2E27 5.1 '⸧' => '⸦';  RIGHT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET => LEFT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET
2E28 5.1 '⸨' => '⸩';  LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS => RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
2E29 5.1 '⸩' => '⸨';  RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS => LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
3008 1.1 '〈' => '〉';  LEFT ANGLE BRACKET => RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
3009 1.1 '〉' => '〈';  RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET => LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
300A 1.1 '《' => '》';  LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET => RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
300B 1.1 '》' => '《';  RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET => LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
300C 1.1 '「' => '」';  LEFT CORNER BRACKET => RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
300D 1.1 '」' => '「';  RIGHT CORNER BRACKET => LEFT CORNER BRACKET
300E 1.1 '『' => '』';  LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET => RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
300F 1.1 '』' => '『';  RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET => LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
3010 1.1 '【' => '】';  LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET => RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
3011 1.1 '】' => '【';  RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET => LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
3014 1.1 '〔' => '〕';  LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
3015 1.1 '〕' => '〔';  RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
3016 1.1 '〖' => '〗';  LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET => RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
3017 1.1 '〗' => '〖';  RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET => LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
3018 1.1 '〘' => '〙';  LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
3019 1.1 '〙' => '〘';  RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
301A 1.1 '〚' => '〛';  LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET => RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
301B 1.1 '〛' => '〚';  RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET => LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
FE59 1.1 '﹙' => '﹚';  SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS => SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS
FE5A 1.1 '﹚' => '﹙';  SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS => SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS
FE5B 1.1 '﹛' => '﹜';  SMALL LEFT CURLY BRACKET => SMALL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
FE5C 1.1 '﹜' => '﹛';  SMALL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET => SMALL LEFT CURLY BRACKET
FE5D 1.1 '﹝' => '﹞';  SMALL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => SMALL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
FE5E 1.1 '﹞' => '﹝';  SMALL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET => SMALL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
FF08 1.1 '（' => '）';  FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS => FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS
FF09 1.1 '）' => '（';  FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS => FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS
FF3B 1.1 '［' => '］';  FULLWIDTH LEFT SQUARE BRACKET => FULLWIDTH RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
FF3D 1.1 '］' => '［';  FULLWIDTH RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET => FULLWIDTH LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
FF5B 1.1 '｛' => '｝';  FULLWIDTH LEFT CURLY BRACKET => FULLWIDTH RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
FF5D 1.1 '｝' => '｛';  FULLWIDTH RIGHT CURLY BRACKET => FULLWIDTH LEFT CURLY BRACKET
FF5F 3.2 '｟' => '｠';  FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS => FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
FF60 3.2 '｠' => '｟';  FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS => FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
FF62 1.1 '｢' => '｣';  HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET => HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
FF63 1.1 '｣' => '｢';  HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET => HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET
```

Comment: Including the code that generated this list (or code that could) would be a nice addition to this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, for a bunch of brackets and their presentation forms, "Bidi_Paired_Bracket" is "None": U+2E02, U+2E03, U+2E04, U+2E05, U+2E09, U+2E0A, U+2E0C, U+2E0D, U+2E1C, U+2E1D, U+FD3E, U+FD3F, U+FE17, U+FE18, U+FE35, U+FE36, U+FE37, U+FE38, U+FE39, U+FE3A, U+FE3B, U+FE3C, U+FE3D, U+FE3E, U+FE3F, U+FE40, U+FE41, U+FE42, U+FE43, U+FE44, U+FE47, U+FE48.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to pick up characters like `<` and `>` that are not formally considered grouping symbols you could take a look at http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/BidiMirroring.txt as suggested by @roeland [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938372/2829764). That file lists all pairs of characters which should be mirror images of each other.

Here's the full list:

```
( ) # { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS
< > # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } SIGN
[ ] # { LEFT, RIGHT } SQUARE BRACKET
{ } # { LEFT, RIGHT } CURLY BRACKET
« » # { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
༺ ༻ # TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS { GYON, GYAS }
༼ ༽ # TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG { GYON, GYAS }
᚛ ᚜ # OGHAM { , REVERSED } FEATHER MARK
‹ › # SINGLE { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
⁅ ⁆ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL
⁽ ⁾ # SUPERSCRIPT { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS
₍ ₎ # SUBSCRIPT { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS
∈ ∋ # { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS AS MEMBER }
∉ ∌ # { NOT AN ELEMENT OF, DOES NOT CONTAIN AS MEMBER }
∊ ∍ # SMALL { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS AS MEMBER }
∼ ∽ # { TILDE OPERATOR, REVERSED TILDE }
≒ ≓ # { APPROXIMATELY EQUAL TO OR THE IMAGE OF, IMAGE OF OR APPROXIMATELY EQUAL TO }
≔ ≕ # { COLON EQUALS, EQUALS COLON }
≤ ≥ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OR EQUAL TO
≦ ≧ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OVER EQUAL TO
≪ ≫ # MUCH { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
≶ ≷ # { LESS-THAN OR GREATER-THAN, GREATER-THAN OR LESS-THAN }
≺ ≻ # { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS }
≼ ≽ # { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS } OR EQUAL TO
⊂ ⊃ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } OF
⊆ ⊇ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } OF OR EQUAL TO
⊏ ⊐ # SQUARE { IMAGE, ORIGINAL } OF
⊑ ⊒ # SQUARE { IMAGE, ORIGINAL } OF OR EQUAL TO
⊢ ⊣ # { RIGHT, LEFT } TACK
⊰ ⊱ # { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS } UNDER RELATION
⊲ ⊳ # { NORMAL SUBGROUP OF, CONTAINS AS NORMAL SUBGROUP }
⊴ ⊵ # { NORMAL SUBGROUP OF, CONTAINS AS NORMAL SUBGROUP } OR EQUAL TO
⊶ ⊷ # { ORIGINAL, IMAGE } OF
⋉ ⋊ # { LEFT, RIGHT } NORMAL FACTOR SEMIDIRECT PRODUCT
⋋ ⋌ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SEMIDIRECT PRODUCT
≃ ⋍ # { ASYMPTOTICALLY EQUAL TO, REVERSED TILDE EQUALS }
⋐ ⋑ # DOUBLE { SUBSET, SUPERSET }
⋖ ⋗ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } WITH DOT
⋘ ⋙ # VERY MUCH { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⋚ ⋛ # { LESS-THAN EQUAL TO OR GREATER-THAN, GREATER-THAN EQUAL TO OR LESS-THAN }
⋜ ⋝ # EQUAL TO OR { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⋞ ⋟ # EQUAL TO OR { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS }
⋰ ⋱ # { UP, DOWN } RIGHT DIAGONAL ELLIPSIS
⋲ ⋺ # { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS } WITH LONG HORIZONTAL STROKE
⋳ ⋻ # { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS } WITH VERTICAL BAR AT END OF HORIZONTAL STROKE
⋴ ⋼ # SMALL { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS } WITH VERTICAL BAR AT END OF HORIZONTAL STROKE
⋶ ⋽ # { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS } WITH OVERBAR
⋷ ⋾ # SMALL { ELEMENT OF, CONTAINS } WITH OVERBAR
⌈ ⌉ # { LEFT, RIGHT } CEILING
⌊ ⌋ # { LEFT, RIGHT } FLOOR
〈 〉 # { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } ANGLE BRACKET
❨ ❩ # MEDIUM { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
❪ ❫ # MEDIUM FLATTENED { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
❬ ❭ # MEDIUM { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
❮ ❯ # HEAVY { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
❰ ❱ # HEAVY { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
❲ ❳ # LIGHT { LEFT, RIGHT } TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT
❴ ❵ # MEDIUM { LEFT, RIGHT } CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT
⟃ ⟄ # OPEN { SUBSET, SUPERSET }
⟅ ⟆ # { LEFT, RIGHT } S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER
⟈ ⟉ # { REVERSE SOLIDUS PRECEDING SUBSET, SUPERSET PRECEDING SOLIDUS }
⟋ ⟍ # MATHEMATICAL { RISING, FALLING } DIAGONAL
⟕ ⟖ # { LEFT, RIGHT } OUTER JOIN
⟝ ⟞ # LONG { RIGHT, LEFT } TACK
⟢ ⟣ # WHITE CONCAVE-SIDED DIAMOND WITH { LEFTWARDS, RIGHTWARDS } TICK
⟤ ⟥ # WHITE SQUARE WITH { LEFTWARDS, RIGHTWARDS } TICK
⟦ ⟧ # MATHEMATICAL { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
⟨ ⟩ # MATHEMATICAL { LEFT, RIGHT } ANGLE BRACKET
⟪ ⟫ # MATHEMATICAL { LEFT, RIGHT } DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
⟬ ⟭ # MATHEMATICAL { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
⟮ ⟯ # MATHEMATICAL { LEFT, RIGHT } FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
⦃ ⦄ # { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE CURLY BRACKET
⦅ ⦆ # { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE PARENTHESIS
⦇ ⦈ # Z NOTATION { LEFT, RIGHT } IMAGE BRACKET
⦉ ⦊ # Z NOTATION { LEFT, RIGHT } BINDING BRACKET
⦋ ⦌ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR
⦎ ⦏ # { RIGHT, LEFT } SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER
⦍ ⦐ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER
⦑ ⦒ # { LEFT, RIGHT } ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
⦓ ⦔ # { LEFT ARC LESS-THAN, RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN } BRACKET
⦕ ⦖ # DOUBLE { LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN, RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN } BRACKET
⦗ ⦘ # { LEFT, RIGHT } BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
⊘ ⦸ # CIRCLED { DIVISION SLASH, REVERSE SOLIDUS }
⧀ ⧁ # CIRCLED { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⧄ ⧅ # SQUARED { RISING, FALLING } DIAGONAL SLASH
⧏ ⧐ # { LEFT TRIANGLE BESIDE VERTICAL BAR, VERTICAL BAR BESIDE RIGHT TRIANGLE }
⧑ ⧒ # BOWTIE WITH { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF BLACK
⧔ ⧕ # TIMES WITH { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF BLACK
⧘ ⧙ # { LEFT, RIGHT } WIGGLY FENCE
⧚ ⧛ # { LEFT, RIGHT } DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE
∕ ⧵ # { DIVISION SLASH, REVERSE SOLIDUS OPERATOR }
⧸ ⧹ # BIG { , REVERSE } SOLIDUS
⧼ ⧽ # { LEFT-POINTING, RIGHT-POINTING } CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
⨫ ⨬ # MINUS SIGN WITH { FALLING, RISING } DOTS
⨭ ⨮ # PLUS SIGN IN { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF CIRCLE
⨴ ⨵ # MULTIPLICATION SIGN IN { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF CIRCLE
⨼ ⨽ # { , RIGHTHAND } INTERIOR PRODUCT
⩤ ⩥ # Z NOTATION { DOMAIN, RANGE } ANTIRESTRICTION
⩹ ⩺ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } WITH CIRCLE INSIDE
⩽ ⩾ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OR SLANTED EQUAL TO
⩿ ⪀ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OR SLANTED EQUAL TO WITH DOT INSIDE
⪁ ⪂ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OR SLANTED EQUAL TO WITH DOT ABOVE
⪃ ⪄ # { LESS-THAN OR SLANTED EQUAL TO WITH DOT ABOVE RIGHT, GREATER-THAN OR SLANTED EQUAL TO WITH DOT ABOVE LEFT }
⪋ ⪌ # { LESS-THAN ABOVE DOUBLE-LINE EQUAL ABOVE GREATER-THAN, GREATER-THAN ABOVE DOUBLE-LINE EQUAL ABOVE LESS-THAN }
⪑ ⪒ # { LESS-THAN ABOVE GREATER-THAN, GREATER-THAN ABOVE LESS-THAN } ABOVE DOUBLE-LINE EQUAL
⪓ ⪔ # { LESS-THAN ABOVE SLANTED EQUAL ABOVE GREATER-THAN, GREATER-THAN ABOVE SLANTED EQUAL ABOVE LESS-THAN } ABOVE SLANTED EQUAL
⪕ ⪖ # SLANTED EQUAL TO OR { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⪗ ⪘ # SLANTED EQUAL TO OR { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } WITH DOT INSIDE
⪙ ⪚ # DOUBLE-LINE EQUAL TO OR { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⪛ ⪜ # DOUBLE-LINE SLANTED EQUAL TO OR { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⪡ ⪢ # DOUBLE NESTED { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⪦ ⪧ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } CLOSED BY CURVE
⪨ ⪩ # { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } CLOSED BY CURVE ABOVE SLANTED EQUAL
⪪ ⪫ # { SMALLER, LARGER } THAN
⪬ ⪭ # { SMALLER, LARGER } THAN OR EQUAL TO
⪯ ⪰ # { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS } ABOVE SINGLE-LINE EQUALS SIGN
⪳ ⪴ # { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS } ABOVE EQUALS SIGN
⪻ ⪼ # DOUBLE { PRECEDES, SUCCEEDS }
⪽ ⪾ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } WITH DOT
⪿ ⫀ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } WITH PLUS SIGN BELOW
⫁ ⫂ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } WITH MULTIPLICATION SIGN BELOW
⫃ ⫄ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } OF OR EQUAL TO WITH DOT ABOVE
⫅ ⫆ # { SUBSET, SUPERSET } OF ABOVE EQUALS SIGN
⫍ ⫎ # SQUARE { LEFT, RIGHT } OPEN BOX OPERATOR
⫏ ⫐ # CLOSED { SUBSET, SUPERSET }
⫑ ⫒ # CLOSED { SUBSET, SUPERSET } OR EQUAL TO
⫓ ⫔ # { SUBSET ABOVE SUPERSET, SUPERSET ABOVE SUBSET }
⫕ ⫖ # { SUBSET ABOVE SUBSET, SUPERSET ABOVE SUPERSET }
⊦ ⫞ # { ASSERTION, SHORT LEFT TACK }
⊩ ⫣ # { FORCES, DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR LEFT TURNSTILE }
⊨ ⫤ # { TRUE, VERTICAL BAR DOUBLE LEFT TURNSTILE }
⊫ ⫥ # DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR DOUBLE { RIGHT, LEFT } TURNSTILE
⫬ ⫭ # { , REVERSED } DOUBLE STROKE NOT SIGN
⫷ ⫸ # TRIPLE NESTED { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN }
⫹ ⫺ # DOUBLE-LINE SLANTED { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } OR EQUAL TO
⸂ ⸃ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
⸄ ⸅ # { LEFT, RIGHT } DOTTED SUBSTITUTION BRACKET
⸉ ⸊ # { LEFT, RIGHT } TRANSPOSITION BRACKET
⸌ ⸍ # { LEFT, RIGHT } RAISED OMISSION BRACKET
⸜ ⸝ # { LEFT, RIGHT } LOW PARAPHRASE BRACKET
⸠ ⸡ # { LEFT, RIGHT } VERTICAL BAR WITH QUILL
⸢ ⸣ # TOP { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF BRACKET
⸤ ⸥ # BOTTOM { LEFT, RIGHT } HALF BRACKET
⸦ ⸧ # { LEFT, RIGHT } SIDEWAYS U BRACKET
⸨ ⸩ # { LEFT, RIGHT } DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
〈 〉 # { LEFT, RIGHT } ANGLE BRACKET
《 》 # { LEFT, RIGHT } DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
【 】 # { LEFT, RIGHT } BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
〔 〕 # { LEFT, RIGHT } TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
〖 〗 # { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
〘 〙 # { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
〚 〛 # { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
﹙ ﹚ # SMALL { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS
﹛ ﹜ # SMALL { LEFT, RIGHT } CURLY BRACKET
﹝ ﹞ # SMALL { LEFT, RIGHT } TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
﹤ ﹥ # SMALL { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } SIGN
（ ） # FULLWIDTH { LEFT, RIGHT } PARENTHESIS
＜ ＞ # FULLWIDTH { LESS-THAN, GREATER-THAN } SIGN
［ ］ # FULLWIDTH { LEFT, RIGHT } SQUARE BRACKET
｛ ｝ # FULLWIDTH { LEFT, RIGHT } CURLY BRACKET
｟ ｠ # FULLWIDTH { LEFT, RIGHT } WHITE PARENTHESIS
```

Answer (score 12):

> What is a good way to search for unicode characters?

This - obviously - depends on what exactly you plan to do. I build the website http://write-math.com. During my bachelors thesis, I created a symbol classifier (which is now on this website under "classify") which gives users the possibility to draw a symbol and get the LaTeX / unicode result (currently only 369 symbols are supported). This is very nice if you want to typeset a document and search single, specific characters of which you know how they look like / how they are called but not how to write them with LaTeX (or whatever you use for typesetting):

[image]

It also has a symbol search feature. It's still in heavy development, but there are 1166 symbols in this database.

For your brackets:

- http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/search/?search=bracket
- http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/search/?search=parenthesis

`unicode.xml` (from http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/#source) is also worth a try.

Comment: Wow, I think that is quite interesting. Good job!

Answer (score 7):

The idea of “bracket-like” characters might be more or less be identified with the General Category (gc) property values of Ps (Punctuation, open) and Pe (Punctuation, close). This category contains a few dozens of paired punctuation marks, mostly excluding quotation marks (categories Pi and Pf).

In programming, many languages have tools for testing for the General Category of a character, e.g. `\p{Ps}` in Perl.

If you just need some lists, you could use the [Unicode Character Categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) information at fileformat.info.

Generally, the way to search for Unicode characters depends on what you are looking for and on your criteria. General Category is a good starting point in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_matching_brackets.html

This is an excellent and very comprehensive website (for brackets and everything else too), and it looks like they display them all using Arial, sans-serif, so if you can see the character, then it should work with good browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Because [andrewdotn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535350/11777065) uses Python 2, here's the Python 3 version:

```py
import re
import unicodedata

for i in range(0x10000):
    char = chr(i)
    category = unicodedata.category(char)
    name = unicodedata.name(char, '')
    if ('bracket' in name.lower() or 'paren' in name.lower()
            or category in ['Ps', 'Pe']):
        print('U+%04x %s %s %c' % (i, category, name, char))
```