# How to use < and > in angular material autocomplete template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've tried to use this using jade (pug) template:

```
md-item-template
  span(md-highlight-text="vm.parent.newUser") {{item.name}} {{item.surname}} <{{item.email | truncate: 42}}>
```

I've also tried using this:

```
md-item-template
  span(md-highlight-text="vm.parent.newUser") {{item.name}} {{item.surname}} &lt;{{item.email | truncate: 42}}&gt;
```

and in both cases I see `&lt;` and `&gt;` as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue using unicode 〈 and 〉taken from answer to this question: [List of all unicode's open/close brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535289/387194)