# Where is the Unicode "discussion on semantics of paired bracketing characters"?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ascii, semantics, parentheses

The Unicode [Basic Latin (ASCII) code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) has the following entries for the parenthesis code points:

```
0028  (  LEFT PARENTHESIS
         = opening parenthesis (1.0)

0029  )  RIGHT PARENTHESIS
         = closing parenthesis (1.0)
         • see discussion on semantics of paired
         bracketing characters
```

As far as I can see, the document has no further information on which "discussion on semantics of paired bracketing characters" it is referring to. I'm guessing it is about "left"/"right" vs "opening"/"closing", but I would like to know more.

When I search the web for phrases like "[semantics of paired bracketing characters](http://google.com/search?q=semantics+of+paired+bracketing+characters)" I only get the same document in various versions.

What discussion is it referring to and where can I read it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13535172/632407

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Paired_Brackets and http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn39/

Comment: @n.m. Thank you. Hm, so the "semantics" in question does not concern the naming as I guessed, but semantics of which brackets in a text should be considered a pair?

Comment: Yes, it's about meaning, not naming.