# Why is Unicode Character 'DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK' (U+201E) not a quotation mark?

Tags: regex, unicode

Even though I stumbled over this because a PHP regex I wrote failed to match it in the way I expected, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. After all, the definition in PHP (and probably other Unicode-aware regex engines) seems to match the official categorization (cf. e.g. 
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201e/index.htm) and it is this official categorization I am unhappy with.

According to this, the DOUBLE LOW-9 **QUOTATION** MARK is categorized as `Ps` (therefore matched by `/\p{Ps}/`) and, in spite of its very name, not as `Pi` (initial quotation mark), for which is used in German. It didn't even make it into the less specific 'Punctuation, Initial quote (may behave like `Ps` or `Pe` depending on usage)' category. What could be the reason for this (mis)categorization? In what languages is it actually used as a `Ps` (i.e., similar to `"("` or `"["` or `"{"`)?

But most importantly: What is a suitable regex that covers all kinds of quotation marks across all languages without enumerating too many individual codepoints?

Comment: Maybe it would work if you had a characater class set up like `[\p{Pi}\x{201E}]` for example? Not sure if there would be other quotation marks missing from `Pi`.

Comment: Also, a list of any such quotation marks used as brackets could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535289/9758194) if you want to dig through it. A quick scan tells me that there are several that fall under `Ps`, `Pe` and `Pf`

Comment: My guess would be that it's used as initial punctuation ***in German***, but not necessarily everywhere else. Perhaps its use is too ambiguous to be generally classifiable as one or the other.

Comment: @deceze Dutch used the „ too in the past, although we seem to have switched to “ later.

Comment: `/[\x{FE41}-\x{FE44}\x{FF02}\x{FF07}\x{FF62}-\x{FF63}\x{2018}-\x{201F}\x{2039}-\x{203A}\x{300C}-\x{300F}\x{301D}-\x{301F}\x{2E42}\x{22}\x{27}\x{AB}\x{BB}]/u` covers all codepoints with `Quotation_Mark` = Y

Comment: @nj_ Seems legit but ignores the "without enumerating too many individual code points" part. I might still use it in my project as a defined constant, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The general categories `Pi` (`Initial_Punctuation`) and `Pf` (`Final_Punctuation`) are not used exclusively for quotation marks, just like `Ps` (`Open_Punctuation`) and `Pe` (`Close_Punctuation`) are not used exclusively for characters that aren’t quotation marks. Rather, `Pi` and `Pf` are used for pairs of characters where *either one* can be opening or closing depending on usage, whereas `Ps` characters are *always* opening and `Pe` characters are *always* closing (ignoring rare or specialised cases). Which of these general categories a character belongs to is based on these considerations and has nothing to do with whether it is a quotation mark, a bracket or something else.

U+201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK is categorised as `Ps` because there is no established orthography in the world where it can be used as a closing mark. It is *always* opening in practice. In contrast, U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK is categorised as `Pi` because it can be both an opening and a closing quote depending on which specific style of quotes you chose.

Unicode has a dedicated property for identifying quotation marks appropriately named `Quotation_Mark`. This property is defined independently from the general category values previously discussed.

Comment: Sounds like a weird rationale. "This is not always at the *end*, it is sometimes at the *start*, so we better call it *final*"?? /rant -- But more importantly for applications: It seems that the `Quotation_mark` property is not available as a shorthand in common regex engines?