# How can sublime text have this symbol?

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I need some symbols with various shapes to distinguish them. I really like the symbols on the picture above, but when I loaded them into the webpage, their appearance changed. After some research, I found out that these symbols are full-width characters, which will take up the width of two characters. However, in Sublime Text, they don't do this. I want to know how Sublime Text does it and whether my webpage can use a similar method to display these symbols.

[symbol in sublime text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZaB8.png)

[same symbol in my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoYAv.png)

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535172/list-of-all-unicodes-open-close-brackets)

Comment: @Miro thanks for your reply, i had tried this before but can only find: ｢｣ , i really want to know how can sublime make other full-width symbol into half-width, but your guiding really help me too, at least i got another choices now :)

Answer (score 0):

Every symbol depend on the font file you are using. As you should know that same emoji is changes on every other android device like whatsapp uses its own emoji and samsung and apple have their own emoji. And if you use UTF-8 emoji or symbol then the symbol will change on changing device maker most of the time. So, I will suggest you to download your custom font file the use that for the font of the symbol. I will suggest you to use [DaFont](https://www.dafont.com/) website for amazing fonts.

### Edited

If changing the font-style does not working means that, that font-style havn't that symbol in its directory. And if there isn't that character or symbol in the directory then it will use app default or system default character. As you should know consolas doesn't have all of these characters you are using, [check this page for supported unicode character for Consolas.](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/consolas/grid.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i still not sure about some details: do you mean i need to use font familiy as same as what Sublime Text 3 using? I search from internet to know that it is Consolas but unfortunatly when i changed my html font with font-familiy: "Consolas", it is not working in my page to this full-width symbol……

Comment: Unluckily there seems like it do not have the symbol i want to use , i still want to know how does sublime made it. But thanks again for providing so many resources! : )